# my servlet is not saving data in my sql

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

hello every one i am learning servlet and i am having a problem while saving data into mysql its not saving in mysql while user enters the value.
hello every one i am learning servlet and i am having a problem while saving data into mysql its not saving in mysql while user enters the value.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;


public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


            String name = request.getParameter ("name");
            String age=request.getParameter("age");

            out.println("your name is " +name+" <br>");
out.println("Your age is " +age+"<br> ");
            try {
             //loading drivers for mysql
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        //creating connection with the database 
          Connection  con=DriverManager.getConnection
                     ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","username=root","password=root");

          PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement
                  ("insert into raa values(?,?)");

        ps.setString(1, name);
        ps.setString(2,age );

        int i=ps.executeUpdate();

            out.println("ACCOUNT REVIEW<br>");




          if(i>0)
          {
            out.println("You are sucessfully registered");
          }

        }
      catch(Exception se)
        {
                        se.printStackTrace();

        }  
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is  the problem ?!

Comment: the data which i am entering in text field is not saving in mysql

Answer (score 1):

`getConnection` doesnt accept the database credentials in name/value pairs. Replace

```
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection
                     ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","username=root","password=root");
```

with

```
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection
                     ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","root");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something wrong with your Connection.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/your_db_name
```

It should be your own database, not the system database mysql.